# Convert Geo Coordinates System X/Y to lat &lon from netCDF4 file using python 3

Tags: coordinate-system, netcdf, python-3

I have netcdf4 file with some variables like: Geo Coordinates System X/Y.
I need to convert it to lat/lon. How can i do that with python?

This information from my netCDF4 file:

```
    import numpy as np
    from netCDF4 import Dataset

     path = '/home/data/Mmultic3kmNC4_msg04_201905080200.
        ...: nc'

    In [78]: f=netCDF4.Dataset(path,'r')

     f.variables.keys()
    Out[80]: odict_keys(['time', 'dtime', 'IR_016', 'commentaires', 'satellite', 'geos', 'ImageNavigation', 'GeosCoordinateSystem', 'Y', 'X', 'Albedo_to_Native_count_IR_016', 'IR_039', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_039', 'IR_087', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_087', 'IR_097', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_097', 'IR_108', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_108', 'IR_120', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_120', 'IR_134', 'Temp_to_Native_count_IR_134', 'VIS006', 'Albedo_to_Native_count_VIS006', 'VIS008', 'Albedo_to_Native_count_VIS008', 'WV_062', 'Temp_to_Native_count_WV_062', 'WV_073', 'Temp_to_Native_count_WV_073'])

    In [81]: IR=f.variables['IR_108']

    In [82]: IR
    Out[82]: 
    <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
    int16 IR_108(ny, nx)
        standard_name: toa_brightness_temperature
        long_name: 10.8 microns infra-red channel MSG Imager
        units: K
        scale_factor: 0.01
        add_offset: 273.15
        valid_min: -27315
        valid_max: 32767
        _FillValue: -32768
        available: yes
        comment: channel 9
        nuc: 931.122
        alpha: 0.9983
        beta: 0.6256
        CalibrationParametersOrigin: rttov
        _CoordinateSystems: GeosCoordinateSystem
        grid_mapping: GeosCoordinateSystem
        resolution: 3.0
        Offset : radiance = offset + CN x slope: -10.456819486590666
        Slope : radiance = offset + CN x slope: 0.2050356762076601
    unlimited dimensions: 
    current shape = (3712, 3712)
    filling on

    print(IR.dimensions)
    ('ny', 'nx')
x=f.variables['X']                                                      

In [3]: x                                                                       
Out[3]: 
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 X(nx)
    standard_name: projection_x_coordinate
    units: m
    _CoordinateAxisType: GeoX
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (3712,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

In [4]: y = f.variables['Y']                                                    

In [5]: y                                                                       
Out[5]: 
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 Y(ny)
    standard_name: projection_y_coordinate
    units: m
    _CoordinateAxisType: GeoY
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (3712,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

y = f.variables['Y'][:]                                                                   

In [12]: y                                                                                         
Out[12]: 
masked_array(data=[ 5568754. ,  5565753.5,  5562753. , ..., -5559743. ,
                   -5562743. , -5565744. ],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=1e+20,
            dtype=float32)
```

[link for file netCDF4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IT-F7AbIx4bCjMLosjBx4F4UCoIX5DU0)

What do I need to use to convert X/Y to lat /lon coordinates?